# Database Component for Firebird using D2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird

I just upgraded my BDS2006 Prof to D2010 Prof. I usually use Interbase component (TIBDatabase, etc) to connect with the database. I am thinking about other alternative components. Sadly, Zeos component (6.X) currently still not working with D2009/D2010. DBExpress support FB connection but not in Prof. Version (only in Enterprise/Architect). 
What component(s) you suggest for me? (I prefer a free good component, but it is okay if it is a very good, stable, robust, not so expensive and well supported commercial product).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use :

- [UIB](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=5) (free)
- [IBDAC](http://www.devart.com/ibdac/)
- [AnyDAC](http://www.remobjects.com/anydac.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The best library for Delphi-Firebird interaction is [FIBPlus](http://www.devrace.com/en/fibplus/). But it is quite expensive - $348 per one license

Comment: Yes it is too expensive. D2010 cost me around 480 USD. 348 USD for a component is too much.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a free [dbExpress driver for FireBird](http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/) which can be used in Delphi 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [IBProvider](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/) (OLE DB Firebird driver and Interbase provider), This very well [documented](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation.html), [updated](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/news/n_090813.html) (last version 13-08-2009) and has great support.

The access to Firebird from Delphi using this provider, you may choose among the following variants:

- Interact with ADO via COM interfaces.
- Use dbGo (ADO Express) components.

Supports the following versions of firebird

- Firebird 1.0 (1.0.3)
- Firebird 1.5 (1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5)
- Firebird 2.0 (2.0.1 - 2.0.x)
- Firebird 2.1
- Firebird 2.5
- Firebird 64 bits

Bye.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, but more than 100USD for such component is still expensive for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another free option is to use the free ODBC driver and the dbGo components.  I use them and they work pretty well.

[Firebird ODBC Driver](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=odbc)

Comment: ODBC means slower connection :) I need the native. Thx anyway!

Comment: Understood!  I will say that I've been pretty pleased with the ODBC connectors speed, but my performance needs are not super high on my project.  Good luck!  Firebird has been a joy to work with so far for me.